# Using mutexes with concurrent futures in Python

Tags: python, mutex, concurrent.futures

I have some code that uses concurrent futures to connect to lots of remote hosts to run some commands.

For example:

```
def set_host_to(host, value):
  connection = connect_to(host)
  info = do_something_with(connection)
  do_some_action(connection, value)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
  for host, value in things_to_do:
    executor.submit(set_host_to, host, value)
```

I've now got a requirement that some of those futures don't run at the same time, but which ones can't be detemined until they've got the `info` above.

Is the right solution some sort of mutexes here? Say `info` (or some part of it) was a string, and 2 futures with the same string shouldn't run at the same time.  How would I go about coding that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a dictionary of locks, using the code below.

```
locks = defaultdict(threading.Lock)
main_lock = threading.Lock() 

with main_lock:
    lock = locks[info]
with lock:
    do_some_action(connection, value)
```

I'm not sure if the main lock is necessary, but this seems to work.