# Multi threading not processing full list

Tags: python, multithreading, list, web-scraping

I am using multi-threading to visit links read from a csv, strangely irrespective of the `max-workers` or even when I remove the multi-threading part, the code runs for an arbitrarily lower number of urls than in the list. I print the list to verify the count. For e.g if the list has 5000 urls, the code stops at 4084, if the links are 13,000 it will stop at 9200, even when it is just 130 links it will stop at 80 or something. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import requests
import xlrd
import concurrent.futures
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


header_added = False
file_location = "Urls.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
all_links = []
for row in range(1, 11000):
     all_links.append(sheet.cell_value(row,0))

print(len(all_links))
i = 0
def get_solution(url):
    global header_added, i
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    ques_div = soup.find('p', class_='header-description')
    ques = ques_div.find('span').text
    ans_divs = soup.findAll('div', class_='puzzle-solution')
    ans = ans_divs[0].text
    print("Solution ", i)
    i += 1
    dict1 ={"Words": ques, "Solution": ans}
    with open('Results10k.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
        if not header_added:
            w.writeheader()
            header_added = True
        w.writerow(dict1)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    result = executor.map(get_solution, all_links)
```

Comment: That is probably not the issue, but all workers write to the same file. I am not sure if open() is thread safe. If open() is not thread safe you might add a mutex or write to individual files and join them later.

Comment: @user_na Those would be thousands of files, any way around this?

Comment: but this happens, even when I remove multi threading and run it in a `for` loop, like a simple loop.

Comment: It could be, that get_solution() crashes for some of the URLs. You could add a try/except in the body of the function and write all crashed URLS to a different file. If this is the problem the numbers should add up to the total number

Comment: @user_na , I think that might be it.

Comment: Have a look at mutexes, for example this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303158/using-mutexes-with-concurrent-futures-in-python

Comment: `max_workers=600` sounds like a terrible idea, by the way, if you don't have 600 cores to spare.

Comment: @AKX it was not 600, it was 4. Lol. I was going up and down on this for long, don't know when I did this intelligent thing. Never ran it with 600 threads though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reworking of your code that doesn't need locks – instead, there's only ever one process that writes to the file.

Also, due to the GIL, using a ThreadPool will be slower than a process-backed Pool.

```
import csv
import multiprocessing

import requests
import xlrd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sess = requests.Session()


def get_solution(url):
    try:
        resp = sess.get(url)
        resp.raise_for_status()
        page = resp.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
        ques_div = soup.find("p", class_="header-description")
        ques = ques_div.find("span").text.strip()
        ans_divs = soup.findAll("div", class_="puzzle-solution")
        ans = ans_divs[0].text.strip()
        return {"URL": url, "Words": ques, "Solution": ans, "Error": ""}
    except Exception as exc:
        print(url, "Error:", exc)
        return {"URL": url, "Words": "", "Solution": "", "Error": str(exc)}


def read_links(file_location):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    all_links = []
    for row in range(1, 11000):
        all_links.append(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))
    return all_links


def main():
    links = read_links("./Urls.xlsx")
    with open("Results10k.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:  # (or multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool)
            for i, result in enumerate(p.imap_unordered(get_solution, links, chunksize=16)):
                if i == 0:
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, result.keys())
                    writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow(result)
                f.flush()  # Ensure changes are written immediately
                if i % 100 == 0:  # Progress indicator
                    print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It says the name `ques` is not defined?

Comment: What says? The code involving `ques` was written by you.

Comment: `multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Freelance\Scripts_ALL\instant.py", line 33, in get_solution
    return {"Words": ques, "Solution": ans}
NameError: name 'ques' is not defined`

Comment: I will check again if I messed up somewhere.

Comment: It doesn't write to the `csv` . I can't figure it out. https://codeshare.io/5M69OR.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Can you give a couple URLs to try this out with since we don't have your XLS file? Replacing the `get_solution()` code with something that just returns a dict works out fine, and the file is certainly written.

Comment: https://www.motscroises.fr/sujet/A-POIL-ET-A-PLUME
https://www.motscroises.fr/sujet/AUX-FORTES-JAMBES
https://www.motscroises.fr/sujet/ANGLE-INTERIEUR-RENTRANT
https://www.motscroises.fr/sujet/ARME-DES-APACHES
https://www.motscroises.fr/sujet/A-PROXIMITE-DE
https://www.motscroises.fr/sujet/A-L-APPARENCE-DU-SON
https://www.motscroises.fr/sujet/A-UNE-DOMINANTE-JAUNE
https://www.motscroises.fr/sujet/AU-DIABLE-VAUVERT

Comment: I added some error handling. Your extraction code doesn't work perfectly for all of those URLs, but for the ones that do work, they do get written into the CSV file just fine.

Comment: When one spends a bit much time struggling with the same code, it sometimes happens that we tend to make silly mistakes or overlook them, even when they are right in front. So, maybe that's it. I am running the code in question now, once it runs for 10k urls I will try again. Strangely, it is the same code in both of them `get_solution`

Answer (score 1):

It could be, that `get_solution()` crashes for some of the URLs. You could add a try/except in the body of the function and write all crashed URLS to a different file.

```
def get_solution(url):
    try:
        ...
    except:
        with open('errors.txt','a+') as f:
            f.write(url+'\n')
```

If this is the problem the numbers should add up to the total number.
Also `open()` is probably not thread safe.

```
file_lock = threading.Lock()
def get_solution(url):
    with file_lock:
        with open('Results10k.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
            ...
```

Comment: Does this lock the thread till the previous has finished? I am trying this now.

Comment: When file_lock is called while another thread is inside the block it will wait for it to finnish before proceeding.

Comment: I got 2 workers, this seems to be working as of now.

Comment: Try to have not  too many workers. If there are too many, the overhead will eat up all benefits.

Comment: there are only 2, it is awfully slow, there are more than a hundred thousand links.

Comment: @AbhishekRai try to slowly  increase. Maybe in steps of the number of your cpu cores. And check your number of URLs/sec

Comment: yea, running 10k now, will see after that. Problem is , if anything goes wrong, starting over all again is a big pain.

Comment: Write processed URLs into a text file then you can load the file in the beginning and use list comprehension on all_links to filter out the ones you have already done.